# Execute code when not true

Tags: python, jinja2

```
want_to_skip={{ skip_var }}

{% if not skip_var | bool %}

HOST={{ host }}
PORT={{ port }}
USER={{ user }}
PASSWORD={{ password }}

{% endif %}
```

I want to execute the code block whenever "skip_var" is no,n,false.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be able to just use `if not`:

```
{% if not skip_var %}

...

{% endif %}
```

Filters (the | syntax) are generally used for modifying a variable for display - eg. `{{ 3.14 | round }}`.

EDIT: I think I may have misread - are you saying that `skip_var` could be a string with the value `"no"` or `"n"` as well? If so, you can do something similar to in python itself:

```
{% if not skip_var or skip_var == "no" or skip_var == "n" %}
```